# Cant Login always failed

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, web

Good day I am a newbie in webdev. Im trying to create a project where in there is a login form that users will input their username and password.Whenever the button is click it will display a message Login successfully and if the username and password is not stored in the xml it will display Login Failed!!.Can someone tell me what is the mistake of the code?Login keeps having alert message Login Failed when button is click.Below is the code.Thanks in advance for help.

here is  the user.xml code

user.xml

```
<users>
    <user>
        <username>A</username>
        <password>12345</password>
    </user>
</users>
```

heres the login.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="frmlogin" name="frmlogin" method="post" action="Login" onsumbit="return false;">
            <p>ENTER USER NAME <input type="text" name="login_username" id="username"></p>
            <p> ENTER PASSWORD <input type="password" name="login_pass" id="password"><br><br>
                <input type="button" class="button" value="Log in" onclick="login()">
            </p>

        </form>
        <script>            
            window.login = function(e)
            {

                if (document.frmlogin.login_username.value == "") 
                {
                    alert("User name is not blank");
                    return;
                }
                else if(document.frmlogin.login_pass.value == "")
                {
                    alert("Password is not blank");
                    return;
                }

                else
                {
                    var xmlDoc;
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {    // IE 5/6
                        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }

                    xhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml');

                    xhttp.open("GET", "user.xml", false);
                    xhttp.send(null);
                    xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;

                    var ktra=true;
                    var xml=xmlDoc.childNodes[0].childNodes[1];

                    var name = xml.childNodes["username"];        
                    var pass=xml.childNodes["password"];
                    for(var i=0;i<xml.childNodes.length;i++){
                        if(xml.childNodes[i].nodeName="username")
                            name = xml.childNodes[i];
                        if(xml.childNodes[i].nodeName="password")
                            pass = xml.childNodes[i];
                    }
                    if(name.textContent==frmlogin.login_username.value &&pass.textContent==frmlogin.login_pass.value)
                    {
                        ktra=true;        

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ktra=false;
                    }

                    if(ktra==true)
                    {
                        alert("Login Successfully !!!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("Login Failed !!!");
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why does your code target IE5 (1999) and IE6 (2001)?

Comment: try a console.log for name and pass

Comment: Your code is extremely insecure at the moment. The user's identity is verified in the client, and nothing is encrypted. I suggest you look further into handling logins, server-side scripting, and basic security protocols before trying to create a login page.

Comment: but my project is to make a login where in everything stored in xml files. However it gives giving me that error can anyone guide me.. I want to use my above code but I cant figure out why it always failed to login thank you

Comment: *but my project is to make a login where in everything stored in xml files.* Between the IE5/6 compatibility checks and the storage in XML files, I'd look for an instructor that has actually done some web development in this decade.

Comment: You are also adding a new property directly on the `window` object which is a bad idea 99% of the time. I think what you're going to find is that your code (sorry to say) is so old and antiquated and has so much that is not being done properly, that most of us wouldn't try to help you fix it. We are STRONGLY suggesting you scrap it and start over.

Comment: i understand maybe I should start over again :( thank you for all your help you are all kind :) can i ask if anyone can give me guide how to make a login page where in username and password stored in xml files.I am really a newbie

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings with "=". Try with `xml.childNodes[i].nodeName=="username"` and the same for the password if. Also do not name variables in other languages different than English. Its hard to read.